# Java: which parser is best to match text according to parenthesis pairs?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

String example:

"(This is level 1. (This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.) Back to level 1.)"

If it is not known in advance how many levels of parentheses there will be (i.e. there could be a Level 4, 5, 6 etc. within Level 3), my understanding is that it is not possible for a regex to match the Level 2 text in the above example. So, for this example, it would not be possible to match the following using regex:

"(This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.)"

I have read about using a parser to do this but I'm not sure which is best. I would be looking for ease of use, speed, and compatibility with Java. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to be able to match specific levels of nested parentheses? Like provide a nested level and get the pattern dynamically?

Comment: What is your end goal i.e. what do you want your output to be?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/RP76IO. A bit different approach to level definition though.

Comment: I want to specify the level of the parenthesis pair, and the program to give me the text between those parentheses. So, in my example, the specified level would be 2, and the program would return the text shown. I hope this answers your queries and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something like this myself last year.

It was easy, you start by searching the last `(` and you store is index. Then you search the first `)` after the index stored. You just need a substring to extract the text between these two index and done :)

For the next level, use the previous index to find the previous/next `(`/ `)` and you have a easy parse ;)

Here is a sample of a simple code to print each level :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "(This is level 1. (This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.) Back to level 1.)";
        searchInto(s);
    }

    public static void searchInto(String s){
        searchInto(s, s.length(), 0);
    }

    public static void searchInto(String s, int from, int to){
        int nextOpen = s.lastIndexOf("(", from-1);
        if(nextOpen >= 0){
            int nextClose = s.indexOf(")", to);

            System.out.println(s.substring(nextOpen + 1, nextClose));
            searchInto(s, nextOpen, nextClose + 1);
        } else
            return;
    }
```

Will print :

```
This is level 3.
This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.
This is level 1. (This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.) Back to level 1.
```

EDIT :

This should cover more ground. This will search for internal block AND block near each other.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        searchInto("(This is level 1. (This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.) Back to level 1.)");
        searchInto("(L1) (L2) (L3)");
        searchInto("(L1) (L2 (L2a)) (L3)");
    }

    public static void searchInto(String s){
        searchInto(s, s, s.length(), 0);
    }

    public static void searchInto(String s, String original, int from, int to){
        int nextOpen = s.lastIndexOf("(", from);
        if(nextOpen >= 0){
            int nextClose = s.indexOf(")", nextOpen);
            String tmp = original.substring(nextOpen + 1, nextClose);
            System.out.println(tmp); //Print the result, use a List to store or treat it directly.
            s = s.substring(0, nextOpen) + "#" + s.substring(nextOpen + 1, nextClose) + "#" + s.substring(nextClose + 1);
            searchInto(s, original, nextOpen - 1, nextClose + 1);
        } else
            return;
    }
```

will output :

```
This is level 3.
This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.
This is level 1. (This is level 2. (This is level 3.) Back to level 2.) Back to level 1.

L3
L2
L1

L3
L2a
L2 (L2a)
L1
```

By using an alternative String to replace already found character, I prevent the code to be stuck on an index. But I print the value from the original to print the correct value (without the `#`character used to replace the `( )` already found)

This is a bit more expensive so this is really if you need to cover every structure.

Comment: But this won't work with strings like "(Lvl1 (Lvl2) Lvl1 (lvl2bis) Lvl1)"

Comment: His example and explanation doesn't specifiy this kind of pattern, but with a bit of time, this could work (I did it a long time ago, need to remember the way ;) )

Comment: My solution provide a recursive-free method, that's why a wrote it :)

Comment: @mlm, concerning your comment, to select a specific level, just add a counter in searchInto(String,int,int) to track the depth of the search, and stop when you reached the correct level (recursive exit condition). Store the result into a variable and check if anything as been found (variable != null)

Answer (score 1):

This should work with strings like this "(Lvl1 (Lvl2) Lvl1 (lvl2bis) Lvl1)" :

```
private static void printLevels(String in) {
    List<String> levels = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if (in.charAt(i) == '(') {
            indexes.add(i);
        } else if (in.charAt(i) == ')') {
            levels.add(in.substring(indexes.remove(indexes.size()-1), i+1));
        }
    }
    for (String string : levels) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

This:

```
String in =  "(Lvl1 (Lvl2) Lvl1 (lvl2bis) Lvl1)";
printLevels(in);
```

Will print:

```
(Lvl2)
(lvl2bis)
(Lvl1 (Lvl2) Lvl1 (lvl2bis) Lvl1)
```